# 404 (Not Found) for PUT and EDIT after enabling Cors

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm using OWIN authentication and testing my Web APIs locally and I got some errors about CORS. I solved the problem just by adding customeHeaders tag in web.config. Now I'm able to login and and also get data. But when I try to PUT or DELETE requests, I get 404 (Not Found) error.

```
 public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}

 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
    }
}
```

and in web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>         
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: can you add code snippet for the controller ?

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I solved the problem by addin "app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);" in Startup.cs